# Выборка в MySQL по дате 2019-11-22

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте собственно столкнулся я с трудностю, вообшем задача сделать поиск по дате, я беру с поля ввода дату в формате 2019-11-22 затем пропускаю ее через strtotime() и получаю формат юникс, в базе дата указана тоже в юниксе, но ничего постоянно не находит, я долго искал в чем дело в надежде что где то просто опечатка, но потом я понял что дата во время форматирования через strtotime() приравнивает часы и минуты к 00 00. Собственно потому я ничего в юникс формате и не находил ибо записи имели ту же дату однако часы и минуты разные в базе. 
Собственно помню когда то на уроках проходили выборку по дате в базе, только я не помню как это было, подскажите пожалуйста, дата в базе указана в unix задача делать выборку по дате не учитывая часы. Спасибо, для наглядности примера представим что база user, ечейка даты date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала преобразовываем функцией `FROM_UNIXTIME` из юникс в обычный формат. затем отсекаем время дня функцией `DATE`

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MY_DATE_FIELD))='2019-11-22';
```